# GitHub Pages React Project shows a blank page (nothing inside <div id="root">)

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

After deploying my GitHub portfolio project ([source repo](https://github.com/ltbd78/portfolio/tree/master)) using:

```
react-scripts build --entry ./src/index.jsx
npx gh-pages -d build
```

The final deployed [page](https://ltbd78.github.io/portfolio/) has nothing inside `<div id="root"></div>`.

I've had a successful deployment with a fresh test react app.

```
npx create-react-app test
```

And when I slowly migrate code to the test react app here are the results:

1. [successful] `package.json` and `index.jsx`
2. [fail] `App.jsx` and remaining components

Here is a portion of my code, full code can be found in the source repo linked above:

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://ltbd78.github.io/test",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": "^3.10.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "loaders.css": "^0.1.2",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.0",
    "react-loaders": "^3.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.58.0",
    "serve": "^14.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start --entry ./src/index.jsx",
    "build": "react-scripts build --entry ./src/index.jsx",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "prettier": "npx prettier --write .",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "npx gh-pages -d build",
    "serve": "npx serve -s build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

`index.jsx`

```
import "./index.scss";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: 
reportWebVitals();
```

`App.jsx`

```
import "./App.scss";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./components/About";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Layout from "./components/Layout";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using react-router, so you will need to specifiy a `basename` atrribute to the Router.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Routes,
    Route,
    Link
} from "react-router-dom";

import './App.scss';
import {Home} from "./views/home/Home";
import {Counter, CounterClassic} from "./views/counter";
import {ListItems} from "./views/list-rendering/ListItems";
import {TodoContainer} from "./views/todos/TodoContainer";

function App() {
    return (
        <Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_URI}>
            <nav>
                <Link to="">Home</Link>
                <Link to="counter">Counter</Link>
                <Link to="counter-classic">Counter (classic)</Link>
                <Link to="list-rendering">List rendering</Link>
                <Link to="todo-list">TODO List</Link>
                <a target="_blank"
                   href="https://github.com/sombriks/react-studies" 
                   rel="noreferrer">See on github</a>
            </nav>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="" element={<Home/>}/>
                <Route path="counter" element={<Counter/>}/>
                <Route path="counter-classic"
                       element={<CounterClassic/>}/>
                <Route path="list-rendering"
                       element={<ListItems items={[
                           {id: 1, label: "One"},
                           {id: 2, label: "two"}]}/>}/>
                <Route path="todo-list" element={<TodoContainer/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

More detailed explanation [here](https://sombriks.com/blog/0044-cra-builds-for-non-root-urls/).

Comment: Still new to React, forgive me for my dumb follow-up question: Do I place it in my `App.jsx` `<Routes basename={process.env.REACT_APP_URI}>`  OR `index.jsx` `<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.REACT_APP_URI}>`

Comment: you are using react-router 6, therefore your BrowserRouter can be aliased as just Router https://github.com/sombriks/react-studies/blob/main/src/App.tsx

no need to keep two Routers. see the article and the github repo with working source code to get the general idea. The source code has a quite handy github action to publish on gh-pages and the article explains a little how things ended up using that `process.env.REACT_APP_URI`.

Comment: So I tried editing `index.jsx` replacing `<BrowserRouter>` with both `<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.REACT_APP_URI}>` and then `<Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_URI}>`. Neither worked on gh-pages. The latter errors when running locally. Am I implementing your solution incorrectly?

Comment: Thanks to your blog, I got closer to the solution!

Apparently keeping everything else unchanged and editing my `App.jsx` from `<Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>` to `<Route path="portfolio" element={<Layout />}>` allowed my home page to render on GitHub! There was no need to add the `basename` parameter. The drawback is that now my localhost starts at:
`http://localhost:3000/portfolio/` instead of `http://localhost:3000/`. I think your solution allows it work for both `/` and `/portfolio` right? If so, that's the next step I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: i just opened a pull request, easier to test using the local script rather than pushing to gh-pages every time https://github.com/ltbd78/portfolio/pull/1

Comment: I merged it with a test branch and deployed, and both local (/) and gh-pages (/portfolio) appears to be working! I'll take some time to digest your code and then update my master to reflect the changes. Thank you so much!

Comment: One follow-up question I have, how does react know to read  
`.env.development` and `.env.production`? I don't see the `packages.json` reference it in any of the scripts.

Comment: @LinsuHan the dotenv files are read by CRA itself, doing the poper transformations to the final output: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: According to the doc, it looks like variables without the prefix `REACT_APP_` is ignored? If so, what is the purpose of including the `PUBLIC_URL` env variable?

Comment: That one is special: 
"Apart from a few built-in variables (NODE_ENV and PUBLIC_URL), variable names must start with REACT_APP_ to work."

Comment: So one drawback with BrowserRouter I noticed is when I refresh the github page, I get a 404 (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/6535624)). It looks like HashRouter is a good solution to this but I can't seem to get the right basename so that it works on github; do you have any ideas? (For now I'm using MemoryRouter as a placeholder).

Comment: sadly not, the 404 happens because this is the way real links work. using github pages we are unable to do the url rewrite to index.html where react routes could then kick in. more details at https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#notes-on-client-side-routing